# How to add sidebar to homepage programmatically?

Tags: themes, templates

I am new in WordPress. I have just created my personal blog. Sidebar widgets is appearing in all pages except homepage. I have realized that I have to add some code manually  to `home-page.php` to show it on homepage but i do not know how to do it. Please help. Here is the code i have in `home-page.php`.

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: Home */
get_header();

get_template_part('home','slider');
$awada_theme_options = awada_theme_options();
foreach($awada_theme_options['home_sections'] as $section){
    get_template_part('home',$section);
}

get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: It appears you are using a theme. Did you create a child theme? If not, any changes you make to the parent theme (Awada), will be overwritten as soon as you update the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send a the code of the pages the sidebar is showing?

But it should normally be before the `get_footer()` function